# certmanager doesn't work anymore after deploying to new instance

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, cert-manager

[image]So I didn't change anything in my k8s deployment. Apparently gitlab changed the integration of GCK and now it is not possible to disable RBAC anymore?
Does anybody know if it is still possible or how I would give the gitlab maanged certmanager enough rights no make the prove?
Thanks in advance!

[image: error from why no padlock]

Comment: Can you show the error message or anything more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: that's the thing i didn't get any errors running the gitlab pipeline. But i have no idea why the cirtmanager didn't work. I added a picture form whynopadlock

Comment: Did you find the issue?